# Android: How to set layout height automatic

Tags: android, layout, height

I want to set layout height automatic like in this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7NOx.png]

Because if I set layout height in `fill_parent` or `match_parent` it looks like this:

[image]

I want something like a `fill_parent` but in the middle.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you can understand.

Comment: Why don't you use weight for that layout?

Comment: set     "Wrapcontent" @Julian Pera

Comment: You should use RelativeLayout for parent.

Comment: @Julián Pera can u upvote my answer?

Comment: @Raghavendra I don't have any button. I can't vote comments. I think it's because i'm newbie in this page.

Comment: @Julián Pera you can see a tick mark in the below answer

Comment: @Raghavendra Done.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use layout weight property of the Layout

Comment: how to use it for that case?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aa"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for setting up layout automatically according to your content

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a crazy answer :)

First make sure to set the constraint then set the height like this `android:layout_height="zeltrax"` then run the app and guess what build output will give you an error with exact number of dp to fit that screen.

Like this: `AAPT: error: 'zeltrax' is incompatible with attribute layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294]`

You have to use `wrap_content=4294967294` in height, like `android:layout_height="4294967294dp"` and you are ready to go.

Thank me later :)